# Opening XML file in Android with inputstream

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a file called `products.xml` in res/xml/products.xml with this XML data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<products>
    <product>     
        <productname>Jeans</productname>
        <productcolor>red</productcolor>
        <productquantity>5</productquantity>
    </product>
    <product>     
        <productname>Tshirt</productname>
        <productcolor>blue</productcolor>
        <productquantity>3</productquantity>
    </product>
    <product>     
        <productname>shorts</productname>
        <productcolor>green</productcolor>
        <productquantity>4</productquantity>
    </product>
</products>
```

and my main goal is to parse it using XMLPullParser. But I'm getting a weird output when I try to open the file. Here is the code I am using:

```
    BufferedReader in = null;
    try {
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(appContext
                .getResources().openRawResource(R.xml.products), "UTF-8"));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        s.append(line);
    }

    System.out.println("String: " + s);
```

and I'm getting a strange output with a bunch of these characters:

```
�������������������������������������������������������������������
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put your XML file into the res/raw folder and then read it with `openRawResource(R.raw.products)` or, if you want to parse it as XML, use `getResources().getXml(id)`, but you'll get an `XmlResourceParser` not a `String`.

Comment: Actually, all I had to do was move the file to res/raw. Why is it that I can't make my own folder and open it from there? Especially since the data WAS in the resulted string, it just included a lot of foreign characters too.

Comment: Resources are _special_ in Android, There is a specific folder structure, and different kind of resources go into different folders, and behave differently. If you want a completely user defined file/folder hierarchy use "Assets" instead.